# How to set ListView Height to auto?

Tags: android, listview, height

I want to set the ListView height to auto means as per my items will add to listview then at that time height will also increase auto automatically.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/abcd_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/blur_default_img">

            <RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/profile_img_rt"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_white_bg">

        <com.example.RoundedImageView.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/person_avatar" />

         </RelativeLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
        <ListView 
           android:id="@+id/tab_pending_list"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_below="@+id/profile_layout">
        </ListView>

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

so this the xml please kindly go through it and suggest me solution that how to increase the height of the listview automatically.

Comment: ya i know that but i have update my post please go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` is a scrollable view so you should never put it inside another scrollable view like a `ScrollView`.

The `ListView` will display only the row describe by the adapter behind it. So all you need to do is to just delete the `ScrollView` and keep the `ListView` with `android:height=wrap_content`